# Find the maximum location of a heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Hi I have a specific problem, that is given a 1-d semi-infinite nonhomogeneous heat equation

$$\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}+\frac{1}{k}g(x,t)=\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}, \quad 0<x<\infty, t>0$$

for any given $t$, is there a way to get the location of maximum i.e. $x_{max}$, for ${T_{max}(x,t)}$ without solving the equation fully?

For example, giving $g(x,t)$ and
boundary condition is $T(0,t)=f(t)$

The solution can be explicitly derived using Laplace transform, Greens' function etc..

But without deriving the solution first, if i just want to find $x_{max}$ associated with $T_{max}(x,t)$ for any given $t$, is there a technique?

Comment: Is the initial condition arbitrary?

Comment: Yeah you may assume uniform initial and periodic sinusoidal boundary condition. I just wonder if there's a technique to get the maximum location of that equation without solving it first.

Comment: I'll say.... I doubt it. If such a method existed, a lot of Conjugate Heat Transfer specialists would find themselves out of a job

Comment: edited thats a typo

Comment: Even given the explicit solution, an algorithm to find the global maximum of a function on $\mathbb{R}$ does not exist.